# Reactjs - adding a read more button to an array to hide/show more than 3 items

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am creating a react app with an array showing list of items, trying to add a read more and hide items if the list item count is more than 3.

my codesandbox is here below. could any one help me with this

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-gates-xtkr4y?file=/src/comp.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could render it conditionally. So you render the first three items of the array with a button that says `read more`. If you click on the button it changes the state of the conditional render to `true`, rendering the whole array instead of the first 3 items. Once you click on `read more` you could change it to `hide` with another conditional, using the same state. Once you press on `hide` again it will set the state to `false` and render the first three items again.

A code example:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [toggleHide, setToggleHide] = useState(false);
  const array = ["apple ", "pear ", "banana ", "melon ", "grapes "];
  const newArray = array.slice(0, 3);
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("read more");

  function handleClick() {
    if (!toggleHide) {
      setButtonText("hide");
    } else {
      setButtonText("read more");
    }
    setToggleHide(!toggleHide);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!toggleHide ? <h1>{newArray}</h1> : <h1>{array}</h1>}
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>{buttonText}</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-readme-w0c7id?file=/src/App.js

Comment: yeah , I am adding the conditions and functions like that the props not showing in my comp component

Comment: @FaizalMunna I created a small demo, I think that's the functionality you're looking for right?

Answer (score 2):

```
 maybe this will help you
```

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const Comp = ({car}) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
    const [more, setMore] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        let arr = [];
        for (let i = 0, t = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); i < t; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
        return () => {
            arr.length >= 3 ? setMore(true) : setMore(false)
            setCount(arr);
        }
    }, []);

    const doSomething = () => {
        console.log('Your Logic Here')
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {count?.length > 0 &&
                count.map((i) => {
                    return <div key={i}>{i}</div>;
                })}
            {more && <button onClick={doSomething}> More List </button>}
        </div>
    );
    // return <li>{car.name}</li>;
};

export default Comp;
```